# intermittent "cannot open DB" errors and crashes

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am developing an Android app in [Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com/)/VS and using [SQLite DB](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/databases/sqlite/) for storing data that workers collect. The app has been tested and in use for a while, but occasionally there are problems opening DB, and it will sometimes exit unexpectedly without saving changes.

I cannot find a clue why it fires cannot open DB error. I tried various combinations and it seems that error fires randomly and not in certain conditions.

It seems Android somehow manages memory and does not allow my app to open DB file.

Can someone give me advice what can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have some error messages? Maybe you can find some in the Google Developer Console (only if you published it through the store)?

Comment: You should be able to put a try..catch at the main program and log the exception